# Change working mouse usb code X & Y from 8-bit to 16-bit

Tags: c, usb, mouse

As you can see below, I changed `HID_USAGE_GENERIC_X` to -32767 and `HID_USAGE_GENERIC_Y` to 32767 to get the greatest possible value range for a 16 bit variable. I also changed `HID_ReportSize` to 16 rather than 8. I read that `wMaxPacketSize` must be greater than the number of packets to be sent, which it should be since that value is set to 8. I believe regarding the USB desc file, I have everything set the way it should be.

So with the original working 8-bit code, I am using a `uint8_t report[report_size]`. When I changed it, I increased the report size to 5 where it was 3 before. My understanding is that:

```
report[0] = mouse buttons, 
report[1] = lower 8 bits of X, 
report[2] = upper 8 bits of X, 
report[3] = lower 8 bits of Y, 
report[4] = upper 8 bits of Y.
```

Is this the correct implementation of a 16 bit X/Y 16-bit variable? I've looked online for something that may help, but nothing seems to be very thorough with what needs to be done.

```
/**
 * HID Mouse Report Descriptor
 */
 const uint8_t Mouse_ReportDescriptor[] = {
    HID_UsagePage(HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC),
    HID_Usage(HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE),
    HID_Collection(HID_Application),
    HID_Usage(HID_USAGE_GENERIC_POINTER),
    HID_Collection(HID_Physical),
    HID_UsagePage(HID_USAGE_PAGE_BUTTON),
    HID_UsageMin(1),
    HID_UsageMax(3),
    HID_LogicalMin(0),
    HID_LogicalMax(1),
    HID_ReportCount(3),
    HID_ReportSize(1),
    HID_Input(HID_Data | HID_Variable | HID_Absolute),
    HID_ReportCount(1),
    HID_ReportSize(5),
    HID_Input(HID_Constant),
    HID_UsagePage(HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC),
    HID_Usage(HID_USAGE_GENERIC_X),
    HID_Usage(HID_USAGE_GENERIC_Y),
    HID_LogicalMin( (uint16_t) -32767),     //was -127
    HID_LogicalMax(32767),                  //was 127
    HID_ReportSize(16),                     //Was 8
    HID_ReportCount(2),
    HID_Input(HID_Data | HID_Variable | HID_Relative),
    HID_EndCollection,
    HID_EndCollection,
};
const uint16_t Mouse_ReportDescSize = sizeof(Mouse_ReportDescriptor);

/**
 * USB Standard Device Descriptor
 */
ALIGNED(4) const uint8_t USB_DeviceDescriptor[] = {
    USB_DEVICE_DESC_SIZE,           /* bLength */
    USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,     /* bDescriptorType */
    WBVAL(0x0200),                  /* bcdUSB : 2.00*/
    0x00,                           /* bDeviceClass */
    0x00,                           /* bDeviceSubClass */
    0x00,                           /* bDeviceProtocol */
    USB_MAX_PACKET0,                /* bMaxPacketSize0 */
    WBVAL(0x1FC9),                  /* idVendor */
    WBVAL(0x0085),                  /* idProduct */
    WBVAL(0x0100),                  /* bcdDevice : 1.00 */
    0x01,                           /* iManufacturer */
    0x02,                           /* iProduct */
    0x03,                           /* iSerialNumber */
    0x01                            /* bNumConfigurations */
};

/**
 * USB FSConfiguration Descriptor
 * All Descriptors (Configuration, Interface, Endpoint, Class, Vendor)
 */
ALIGNED(4) uint8_t USB_FsConfigDescriptor[] = {
    /* Configuration 1 */
    USB_CONFIGURATION_DESC_SIZE,            /* bLength */
    USB_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,      /* bDescriptorType */
    WBVAL(                                  /* wTotalLength */
        USB_CONFIGURATION_DESC_SIZE   +
        USB_INTERFACE_DESC_SIZE       +
        HID_DESC_SIZE                 +
        USB_ENDPOINT_DESC_SIZE
        ),
    0x01,                           /* bNumInterfaces */
    0x01,                           /* bConfigurationValue */
    0x00,                           /* iConfiguration */
    USB_CONFIG_SELF_POWERED,        /* bmAttributes */
    USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA(2),             /* bMaxPower */

    /* Interface 0, Alternate Setting 0, HID Class */
    USB_INTERFACE_DESC_SIZE,        /* bLength */
    USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,  /* bDescriptorType */
    0x00,                           /* bInterfaceNumber */
    0x00,                           /* bAlternateSetting */
    0x01,                           /* bNumEndpoints */
    USB_DEVICE_CLASS_HUMAN_INTERFACE,   /* bInterfaceClass */
    HID_SUBCLASS_BOOT,              /* bInterfaceSubClass */
    HID_PROTOCOL_MOUSE,             /* bInterfaceProtocol */
    0x04,                           /* iInterface */
    /* HID Class Descriptor */
    /* HID_DESC_OFFSET = 0x0012 */
    HID_DESC_SIZE,                  /* bLength */
    HID_HID_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,        /* bDescriptorType */
    WBVAL(0x0111),                  /* bcdHID : 1.11*/
    0x00,                           /* bCountryCode */
    0x01,                           /* bNumDescriptors */
    HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,     /* bDescriptorType */
    WBVAL(sizeof(Mouse_ReportDescriptor)),  /* wDescriptorLength */
    /* Endpoint, HID Interrupt In */
    USB_ENDPOINT_DESC_SIZE,         /* bLength */
    USB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE,   /* bDescriptorType */
    HID_EP_IN,                      /* bEndpointAddress */
    USB_ENDPOINT_TYPE_INTERRUPT,    /* bmAttributes */
    WBVAL(0x0008),                  /* wMaxPacketSize */
    HID_MOUSE_REPORT_INTERVAL,      /* bInterval */
    /* Terminator */
    0                               /* bLength */
};
```

Comment: Can you set 8-bit fields to 16-bit values?

Comment: Yes, mouse resolution would be awful if you weren't able to adjust that to a bigger variable size.

Comment: So please explain how an 8-bit field stores a 16-bit value? Is it a token representation of some kind?

Comment: ... as in `HID_LogicalMin( (uint16_t) -32767)`

Comment: It doesn't. If you look at the code above, Report Size is the number of bits to be represented in the report. I could have made it 0 - 2^16, but I prefer the origin in the center of the screen, so I use -32767 and 32767.